# What's the most idiomatic way to test two Options for equality when they contain values which can be tested for equality?

Tags: rust

I have two types that can be tested for equality. However, once I wrap them in `Option`s, the nicety provided by various `PartialEq` implementations goes right out the window. I have to use `map` or otherwise convert them.

As an example, let's use `&str` and `String`:

```
fn main() {
    let a = "hello";
    let b = "hello".to_owned();

    assert_eq!(a, b); // Just fine

    let a = Some(a);
    let b = Some(b);

    // error: mismatched types
    assert_eq!(a, b);

    // error: mismatched types
    assert_eq!(a, b.as_ref());

    // works, but highly tied to strings or slices,
    // requires me to remember which is which
    assert_eq!(a, b.as_ref().map(|x| &x[..]));
}
```

There surely must be a simpler or more straight-forward way to do this?

Side-question — what prevents `Option` from implementing `PartialEq` a bit more broadly? I'm guessing coherence, my *old nemesis*.

```
impl<T, U> PartialEq<Option<U>> for Option<T>
where
    T: PartialEq<U>,
```

There's some chatter about this in the [RFCs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/917) and Rust issues ([1](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20063), [2](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20927)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Rust 1.40, you can use [`as_deref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref) so you don't have to remember what is what:

```rust
assert_eq!(a.as_deref(), b.as_deref());
```

Before Rust 1.40, I would do something like this:

```
match (&a, &b) {
    (Some(a), Some(b)) => assert_eq!(a, b),
    (None, None) => (),
    _ => panic!("a and b not equal"),
}
```

---

Another option is a custom assertion, based on [`assert_eq!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/macros.rs.html#53-80):

```
macro_rules! cmp_eq_option {
    ($left:expr, $right:expr) => {{
        match (&$left, &$right) {
            (Some(left_val), Some(right_val)) => *left_val == *right_val,
            (None, None) => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }};
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! assert_eq_option {
    ($left:expr, $right:expr) => ({
        if !cmp_eq_option!($left, $right) {
            panic!(r#"assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `{:?}`,
 right: `{:?}`"#, $left, $right)
        }
    });
    ($left:expr, $right:expr,) => ({
        assert_eq_option!($left, $right)
    });
    ($left:expr, $right:expr, $($arg:tt)+) => ({
        if !cmp_eq_option!($left, $right) {
            panic!(r#"assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `{:?}`,
 right: `{:?}`: {}"#, $left, $right, format_args!($($arg)+))
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be technical reason blocking this, it looks like it's just a matter of doing the implementation work.

Comment: I did actually try to land a patch to Rust to add this. However, it turns out that it's not easy to add this to the language as it exists at version 1.1. One of the main issues is that `None` would become ambiguous, and you would have to specify *which kind of `None`* you meant: `None::<u8>`. Obviously, this is pretty terrible for ergonomics.

Comment: This is not a very good answer. So how do you do the equality check? With `map`?

Comment: @Shepmaster Wait, why? What about `==` breaks type inference?

Comment: @NicHartley in the proposed patch, it was something like `impl PartialEq<Option<U>> for Option<T> where U: PartialEq<T>`. This means that `Option<String>` can be compared to `Option<&str>`, but `None` by itself is ambiguous as to what type it contains. Should `Some(String::new()) == None` use the comparison code for `String` or for `&str`?

Comment: @Shepmaster I would expect Some(String::new()) == None to use String comparison, and if you wanted to use &str, you would do Some(String::new()) == Option::<&str>::None to put a type on the literal None.

Comment: @DanielV you might expect that, but that's not how Rust's trait system is currently designed. Perhaps you could contribute to the trait system implementation to enable something that would enable that!