# Different types of string.chars(), for .next() and .peek()

Tags: rust, iterator

I'm trying to use `string.chars().peekable()` and the problem I have is that I have different types from `.next()` and `.peek()`. One is `Option<char>`, second is `Option<&char>`, and I have trouble to compare them.

My code is (`s` is `String`):

```
    let mut left_iter = s.chars().peekable();
    let mut right_iter = s.chars().rev().peekable();
    loop {
        let left = left_iter.next();
        let right = right_iter.next();
        let left_next = left_iter.peek();
        let left_right = right_iter.peek();
        if left == right || left == right_next {
          ...
        }
```

The error I get is obvious:

expected `&char`, found `char`

But I can't find a way to have both `next()` and `peek()` having the same type without re/deconstructing Option.

Is there a clean way to have both return values having the same type?

Comment: Related: [What's the most idiomatic way to test two Options for equality when they contain values which can be tested for equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429801/whats-the-most-idiomatic-way-to-test-two-options-for-equality-when-they-contain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options **derefenccing** (`&T` -> `T`) one or **referencing** (`T` -> `&T`) the other:

### Dereferencing

Since they are wrapped in `Option`, you could [`zip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.zip) them and operate over with map, pattern match or dereference the referenced one, otherwise return `false`.:

```rust
fn main() {
    let left = Some('c');
    let right = Some(&'c');
    println!("{}", right.zip(left).map(|(&r, l)| r == l).unwrap_or(false));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6192c96b4ec2cb9bf6ee0e6b92e67b41)

Or since `char` is `Copy`, you could use [`Option::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.copied):

```rust
fn main() {
    let left = Some('c');
    let right = Some(&'c');
    println!("{}", left == right.copied());
}
```

### Referencing

Also, and maybe simpler, you could use `as_ref` to get an `Option<&T>` from an `Option<T>`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let left = Some('c');
    let right = Some(&'c');
    println!("{}", left.as_ref() == right);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9084fdd516a0a4c4d63ce0ca8e2afbbf)

Comment: I love `.copied`. It sounds the most universal (for char case). Thanks!